# How to download all the e-mail messages from POP3 server to a single text file with mailx?

Tags: email, fetchmail, mailx

I would like to download all the e-mails in my old e-mail server. It uses POP3 and I'm interested in e-mails in "Inbox" and "Sent" folders. Once I have downloaded all the messages, I would like to make a script which lists all the e-mails between my e-mail address and one certain e-mail address in chronological fashion into single text file.

However, at first, I think I need to download all the messages to a single file with headers including dates and then create a sorting script. How to approach this?

I have used mailx in scripts for sending mails, but is it possible to use mailx to download all the mails from POP3 server into a single file?

Comment: POP3 only supports an Inbox, with no additional folders on the server.  ([RFC 1939](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1939.html) Sec 8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditional mailx does not support IMAP or POP, but the one that comes with Linux does.

For your particular problem, I recommend using `fetchmail` instead.  You can use the [`--mda`](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/fetchmail-man.html#9) option to have `fetchmail` execute a script of your choice for each downloaded message.  It can even pass the From and To addresses as parameters to your script if you use `%F` and `%T` as placeholders in the command line.

First, create a `mailsorter` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

dest_mbox="$1"
from="$2"
to="$3"

case "$from-$to" in
  someone@example.net-myname)
     echo "From $from  `date`" >> "$dest_mbox"
     cat >> "$dest_mbox"
     ;;
  *)
     cat > /dev/null
     ;;
esac
```

Then run `fetchmail -u myname popserver.example.com --mda './mailsorter /tmp/mbox %F %T'`

While testing this solution, give `fetchmail` the `--all` and `--keep` flags to make sure that you don't delete your mail accidentally.

Comment: Thanks! `Fetchmail` was exactly what I was looking for. However, there is one problem- if I fetch all my e-mail over POP3, I still download only the ones I see in "Inbox" folder in web front-end. However, I would like to access e-mail in "Send" and "Deleted" folders as well. Is this possible?

Comment: POP3 has no concept of any folder other than Inbox. Your Sent and Deleted folders probably reside locally on the client.

Comment: 200_success, ok, I see. However, I have only used this e-mail account through web-interface. I found one way to access "Sent" and "Deleted" folders by coping e-mails from those folders to "Inbox". The other and more sane option would be probably to use IMAP if my web-mail provider supports it as IMAP should support other folders besides "Inbox"?

Comment: IMAP does support multiple folders. Use `fetchmail --folder Sent` (or `fetchmail INBOX.Sent` with some IMAP servers' folder layout).